# What is the timezone that Facebook publish the scheduled posts?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, timezone

I am using Facebook graph API to post on pages

What is the timezone that Facebook publish the scheduled posts in pages?

Is it the admin timezone?

Like this: 1354308243

Comment: Exact duplicate of [how to publish scheduled post with timezone using facebook graph api](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/13651174/how-to-publish-scheduled-post-with-timezone-using-facebook-graph-api)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about facebook api, but this looks like unix timestamp, which is a number of seconds since *epoch* and *epoch* is Jan 1st, 1970 **UTC**.

Comment: my question is about facebook api graph  ...not about unix stamp concept

Comment: Taking into account, that facebook specifies the parameter in question — https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/#posts — as `UNIX timestamp`, your question is either about the unix timestamp concept or about how to read documentation.

Comment: i didn't find it in documentation 

if i convert 7 pm with my local time to unixstamp ....will differ if i convert 7 pm @paris time zone to unix stamp ...so my question is ...what is the timezone that facebook uses to publish my posts ...is it the admin timezone??or what ?? is it clear ??

Comment: Of course it will differ. Unix timestamp specifies a point in time, not on the clock dial. Of course 7pm Paris time and 7pm your local time differs, unless you're in Paris timezone (like me). Unix timestamp, on the other hand, has *no* time zone. It is *again* — a number of second since midnight Jan 1st, 1970 UTC. It means, for instance, that it's a number of seconds since 1am Jan 1st, 1970 Paris time.

Comment: so my question is ........what is the timezone that facebook uses to publish my posts ...is it the admin timezone??or what ??

Comment: I've just told you that unix timestamp has **no** time zone as it specifies point in time. At any given time all timezones and even other planets exist and experience this time. If you have function that converts local time to unix timestamp, then the input is your local time. If you use function that has a timezone parameter — it is the timezone you specify. The output ultimately will be a number of seconds since epoch. Epoch is specified in **UTC** (see my answer and comment), but, again, it's not a timezone of the timestamp.

Comment: If, on the other hand, you're asking about time that is shown to user, then it's going to be user time or whatever time user specified in FB settings (I don't remember if it's possible).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20416/discussion-between-manhag-and-michael-krelin-hacker)

Answer (score 0):

What you are dealing with is called timestamp which doesn't mess up things with timezone at all because you calculate the timestamp of your time in timezone and work with it. And whatever time it will be across different parts of the world, it will happen exactly on the specified time.

So instead of saying post it on 7PM, convert the 7PM into timestamp and wotk with that number, like post it on 1354308243. Makes sense?

Comment: if i convert 7 pm with my local time to unixstamp ....will differ if i convert 7 pm @paris time zone to unix stamp  ...so my question is ...what is the timezone  that facebook uses to publish my posts ...is it the admin timezone??or what ??

Comment: You are confusing yourself with timestamp here. Here for a single timestamp value, times will be different in different timezones. So to post as per a local time, just convert that local time in timezone and use that, as simple as that. FB itself asks for timestamp only - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/#posts

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem by setting my php script to use UTC, but timestamp I used created +2 hours time in Facebook. After investigation and checking reference API I found that the user's timezone is offset from UTC

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=me%3Ffields%3Dtimezone&version=v2.10

I saw that my timezone is +2 from UTC time, so I changed it in php script to adjust it. Now it is working OK.

So I assume it relies on admin timezone.